# Is there a way to setup autologin on Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista

I'd like to setup autologin after booting up vista.  Is there a way to get this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click on the Start button and type in ‘netplwiz‘. This will open the Advanced User Accounts menu
2. In the Users tab, highlight the account you want to login to Vista automatically with, and then untick ‘must enter a username and password to use this computer’
3. Click on ‘Apply’. A new window will now popup asking you to enter the password of the account you’ve just highlighted. Do this, and then click ‘Ok’
4. Click ‘Ok’ on the Advanced User Accounts menu to finish